# Address of a pointer knowing the initial address

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I have the following code:

```
int main(){
int tab[5]={10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
int *ptr;
ptr=tab+4;
printf("%d,%#x,%#x. \n",*ptr-1,&tab,ptr);
return 0;}
```

"tab" is located in a memory zone that starts in the dress 0x28FEF8.

I know that the value of *ptr-1 is 49, and the value of &tab is 0x28FEF8.

Can someone explain me why the value of "ptr" is 0x28FF08? I was guessing it would be 0x28FEFC.

Thank you in the advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we "draw" your array as it is laid out in memory it will look something like

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Then you need to remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, i.e. `tab` is equal to `&tab[0]`. And then you need to remember that for any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is exactly equal to `*(a + i)`. From that it's easy to deduce that `tab + 4` is equal to `&tab[4]`, i.e. a pointer to the fifth element.

So if we again draw the array, but now with pointers:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
^                   ^
|                   |
&tab[0]             &tab[4]
|
&tab
```

If `&tab[0]` is equal to `0x28fef8` then `&tab[4]` is equal to `0x28fef8  + sizeof(int) * 4`, as it is pointing to index 4 of an `int` array, and it's indeed `0x28ff08`.

Please note that while `&tab[0]` and `&tab` are pointing to the same location, they are semantically different. `&tab[0]` is a pointer to a single elements and is of type `int *`, while `&tab` is a pointer to the array and is of type `int (*)[5]`.

---

On a related note, the correct format to print `void *` pointers is `"%p"`. So your printing should really be

```
printf("%d,%p,%p. \n", *ptr-1, (void *) &tab, (void *) ptr);
```

Note that the cast to `void *` really is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I get it now! :)